# Xcode 4.2 and lambda expressions (OSX Lion)

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, xcode4.2

I am trying to get C++11 features to compile on my Mac. I have tried two different things so far. First, the latest Xcode (4.2) claims to support "C++11 features" but when I try to compile this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int n = [] (int x, int y) { return x + y; }(5, 4);
    cout << n << endl;
}
```

I get an error, "expected expression," for the first bracket ([). I'm guessing lambda expressions are not included in the new C++11 features?

Then, as a work around I downloaded gcc 4.6 binaries from http://hpc.sourceforge.net/ but when I use gcc-4.6 (/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.6 -std=c++0x test.cpp) I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::cout", referenced from:
      _main in cctnMUFF.o
...
```

I'm thinking it's an issue with not finding the standard library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XCode 4.2 ships with a late Clang 2.9, patched by Apple. It does not support lambda's nor uniform initializers. Clang 3.0 doesn't either, so you'll have to wait until at least Clang 3.1 (which is due in 6 months from now).

Alternatively, you could use Macports' GCC 4.6 for lambda support.

---

UPDATE to your update: you need to link with `g++`, or add `-lstdc++` manually.

Comment: aha! It worked! Just needed to use g++ instead. At least I can compile manually for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Support for lambda was added in gcc 4.5. Xcode uses gcc 4.2 and it's very unlikely it will be ever upgraded to a newer version (most probably due to newer versions of gcc being licensed with GPL3). Let us know if you manage to configure Xcode to work with gcc 4.5 or 4.6...
Apple is switching to Clang therefore. Let's hope Clang will support (most of) C++11 features soon...

Comment: piokuc: Clang lready supports tons of C++11 features, just not lambda's (very unfortunately). See here for the current state of things: http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html

Comment: Looks like lambda support has been added to the svn version of Clang recently. So hopefuly the next (post 4.3) version of Xcode will have C++ lambda support as well.